# Adding a customTableView onto a view not loading json data properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

In the viewController I want to present/addSubview my VoidTableView onto my viewController. I used the following code in ViewDidLoad to add it to the viewController and it does appear on my viewController accordingly, but does not load the data.

```
// VoidTableView
VoidTableView *controllerVoid;
UITableView *voidTableView ;

controllerVoid = [[VoidTableView alloc]init];
voidTableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 222, 481, 400)];
voidTableView.delegate = controllerVoid;
voidTableView.dataSource = controllerVoid;
```

In my VoidTableView.m file, I have a method which uses an webAPI to retrieve json data and save it onto _dataarray. I am getting the data but it is not displaying onto the table. When I return an integer instead of _dataarray.count for numberOfRows, the table loads but with (null) values. When I return _dataarray.count, the table doesn't seem to load at all. I think I am missing a crucial step in loading the array into the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Can someone please help?

EDIT: _dataarray is a NSArray property declared in VoidTableView.h. My table view code is below and I have a method loadSalesHistory in VoidTableView.m that saves all the data into _dataarray.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
```

Even though the data is being saved into _dataarray, the count still states that it is 0.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@"////// %lu",(unsigned long)_dataarray.count); // is 0
return [_dataarray count];
//  return 3;
}
```

CellForRowAtIndex should be standard to how most people would write it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell ;
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (cell == nil){

}
UILabel *cusdata = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(05, 10, 300, cell.bounds.size.height)];
NSString *datestr = [[_dataarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Date"];
NSString *timestr = [[_dataarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Time"];

NSString *amountstr = [[_dataarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"SoldAmount"];
amountstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",amountstr];
NSNumber *pointsstr = [[_dataarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Points"];
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 12, 70, 40)];
UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(370, 12, 70, 40)];
label2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter ;
label3.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter ;
label2.text = amountstr ;
label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pointsstr] ;
[cell.contentView addSubview:label2];
[cell.contentView addSubview:label3] ;

NSString *cusdatastr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@         %@    ",datestr,timestr];
[cell.contentView addSubview:cusdata];
cusdata.text = cusdatastr ;

return cell;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

return 60 ;
}
```

I've also put an NSLog in ViewDidLoad in VoidViewTable but it never appears even when I do load the table. Could this be the issue?

Comment: You mention _dataarray a few times are you going to leave us all in suspense about what it is and where it is used in your code?

Comment: @MartinH Sorry, I've updated my post

Comment: There's still nothing in your post, a few lines that all. Using a table view there are several methods you must implement. Where are they?

Comment: You've been down voted lots now, maybe better to delete this question and start a new question with more code, people won't view this question much with down votes

Comment: " the count still states that it is 0." then you need to find out why. You can't display the data if there is none

Comment: Try [voidTableView reloadData]; after _dataarray is filled.

Answer (score 0):

First, never add add things to the cell's content view unless you do logic to check if an object has already been added to the subview. [Look here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20018567/uicollectionview-shows-only-the-first-item/23573971#23573971).

Second, follower Retterdesdialog's answer and put the `[tablewView reloadData];` in the method that is called when you receive your json response, such as `didReceiveResponse:` delegate method for NSURLConnection.

You also need to add the table view to the newly created view's subview in either viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.